# Typescript error for data-* attributes on MaterialUI React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to pass a `data-testid` attribute to a Material-UI `Select` component, but I am getting the following Typescript error:

> Type '{ "data-testid": string; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"data-testid"' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes'.
>
> Select.d.ts(111, 3): The expected type comes from property 'SelectDisplayProps' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps'

This is caused by the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

export default function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <Select SelectDisplayProps={{ "data-testid": "my-component" }}>
            <MenuItem value="1">One</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="2">Two</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="3">Three</MenuItem>
        </Select>
    );
}
```

It seems like this is not a problem when data-* attributes are passed directly to a component (e.g. `<Select data-testid="my-component" />`), so the issue is with passing it to `SelectDisplayProps`.

All `SelectDisplayProps` does is pass the props on to a child element inside `<Select>` ([docs](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props)).

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 10):

You can find the type of `SelectDisplayProps` here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/Select/Select.d.ts#L115

> `SelectDisplayProps?: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>;`

You can extend this as needed (`MySelectDisplayProps` in the example below):

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

interface MySelectDisplayProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  "data-testid"?: string;
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("1");
  return (
    <Select
      value={value}
      onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value as string)}
      SelectDisplayProps={
        { "data-testid": "my-component" } as MySelectDisplayProps
      }
    >
      <MenuItem value="1">One</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="2">Two</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="3">Three</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit data attribute in SelectDisplayProps]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although this does work, there isn't much benefit to using this method rather than adding a `@ts-ignore` comment if it has to be included everywhere this is used. Does Typescript have any feature that allows you to override the `HTMLAttributes` interface to allow `data-testid` to be used globally? I'm not sure why it doesn't allow it in the first place. Maybe this is even a bug in the MaterialUI type definitions?

Comment: @twiz I did a little research and this is documented here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18874. I recommend that you upvote the [typescript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28960) that [Sebastian mentions](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18874#issuecomment-569229817).

Answer (score 0):

The MUI Select component provides a `inputProps` that allows you to pass data attributes to the unlying `<input>` element.

If you are looking to set `data-testid` on the outer-most element instead, I was able to do that by passing it directly on the  MUI component, like so.

```
<Select
  value={age}
  label="Age"
  onChange={handleChange}
  data-testid="testing-select"
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```