How to do a general typescript definition to allow data attribute in notification?
I need to add an attribute to a snackbar notification (notistack).
Therefore I do
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack'

const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()
enqueueSnackbar('message', {
  variant: 'success',
  SnackbarProps: { 'data-testid': 'notification' } // throws ts error
})

as it is shown in the docs, but which gives me a ts error:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''data-testid'' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.

So I added this definition:
interface SnackbarProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  'data-testid'?: string
}

const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()
enqueueSnackbar('message', {
  variant: 'success',
  SnackbarProps: {
    'data-testid': 'notification'
  } as SnackbarProps
})

It works, but I would have to add this to every file and every line, where I'm using the notification.
Is it possible to do this definition in general?

Global Interfaces are really discouraged, you can just create a snackbar-props.d.ts file, export the interface in there and import it in your files

@LucaKiebel It is not possible to extend the definition of the option object in enqueueSnackbar()? Right now I always have to add as SnackbarProps.

See here. I'm kinda surprised that HTMLAttributes doesn't declare data attributes already like this.

Duplicate of html data-* attribute has to be explicitly defined with TS or Typescript error for data-* attributes on MaterialUI React component?

@Bergi This is exactly what I am doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482645/3142695 and in the type definition of notistack: https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/blob/a61155adc85443f01dfc8818b6b6653edbd83288/src/types.ts#L264

Yes it's annoying. If you want to get rid of the as, you can do interface declaration merging of either notistack's SharedProps or react's HtmlAttributes (like in the third snippet of this answer)
